# Python unit testing with Docker and environment variables

Tags: python, docker, unit-testing, environment-variables, github-actions

I am trying to run unit tests for my application with a Docker container (and possibly in a GitHub workflow), but I can't figure out how to correctly pass env variables to it.

So normally for the building process I have a pretty standard Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.15

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY src/ .

CMD [ "python3", "main.py" ]
```

and a workflow that builds it and pushes the image to Docker Hub. Then of course the usual `docker run --env-file=.env ...` command to run the application fetching the variables from a file.

Now I am adding tests to the code. The application needs some env variables to function properly (auth keys and other stuff), and so of course also to run the tests. I don't want to export the variables in my system and run the test from my terminal, so I want to use Docker. But I'm not really sure how to properly do it.

My goal is to be able to run the tests locally and to also have a workflow that runs on PRs, without committing the variables in the repo.

This is what I've tried so far:

- Add test to the Dockerfile: adding `RUN python -m unittest -s tests` doesn't really work because at build time Docker doesn't have access to the .env file
- Add GitHub workflow with the test command: even using a GitHub environment to store secrets and deploying the job into that for some reason doesn't fetch the variables. Plus I would like to be able to test the code before pushing the changes, and have this workflow run only on PRs.

```yaml
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: test
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python 3.7
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.7
          cache: 'pip'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Run tests
        shell: bash
        env:
          EMAIL: ${{ secrets.EMAIL }}
          AUTH_KEY: ${{ secrets.AUTH_KEY }}
          ZONE_NAME: ${{ secrets.ZONE_NAME }}
          RECORD_ID: ${{ secrets.RECORD_ID }}
          CHECK_INTERVAL: ${{ secrets.CHECK_INTERVAL }}
          SENDER_ADDRESS: ${{ secrets.SENDER_ADDRESS }}
          SENDER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.SENDER_PASSWORD }}
          RECEIVER_ADDRESS: ${{ secrets.RECEIVER_ADDRESS }}
        run: |
          python -m unittest discover -t src -s tests
```

[Here](https://github.com/DaruZero/cloudflare-dns-auto-updater/tree/test/12/feature-add-testing) you can find the full source code if needed.

Comment: Try `docker run --env-file=.env image_tag python -m unittest -s test`!

Comment: Can you restructure your unit-test setup to not need these credentials?  (This might involve building mock implementations of the things that use them.)  Then you won't need to inject them into your test infrastructure, and you could potentially run the unit tests before you build an image instead of after.

Comment: @DavidMaze not really, since the functions I'm testing need to call the CloudFlare APIs, and so they need authentication for that

Comment: @KlausD. that works for local testing, thanks! But I also need something for the GH workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
RUN python -m unittest -s tests
```

to

```
CMD python -m unittest -s tests
```

and unittest will be launched not at build stage but at tests container start, when you can use your env file

Comment: So basically having a second Dockerfile to run the tests with, right?

Comment: Yes it is good solution. And in Dockerfile for tests you can install lin for tests and do not install them in production docker image

Comment: Yeah makes sense. But then how would I setup a GH action to also run same container without uploading the env file?

Comment: Add for run tests another job (not deploy main container) in GitHub and use same env secrets in GitHub